# Import sql file invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, import

i try to import a SQL file in my Rails app with postgresql database but when i run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(IO.read("tmp/FILE.SQL"))`

I got this error `(PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x80`

I never found answer here with `0x80` error code
When i check with `file` command i got this `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines (334), with CRLF line terminators`

I can't change the sql file because it's from client so parsing of the file without import can be another solution if the problem from the file

Comment: What is the output of `file tmp/FILE.sql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance that your data has the Euro symbol within?  Character 0x80 is € in Win-1252 character set.  If that's what's going on then try this method of converting to UTF-8:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(File.read('tmp/FILE.SQL', encoding: 'cp1252').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it works now i have syntax error with "`"